# Django serializers.save() does not use postgres

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have the following function that runs automatically with cronjob, it makes predictions based on an anomaly detection model and it saves the results to a `postgres` database:

```
def prediction_job():
    """
    This job will run once every batch_minutes minutes to predict if the IPs appear in these batch_minutes minutes are normal or malicious
    and save the results to postgres
    """

    ip_estimator = IpStatePrediction()
    predictions = ip_estimator.predict_ip_state()

    predictions_dict_final = convert_dict_for_serializer(predictions)
    serializer_result = PredictionsSerializer(data=predictions_dict_final)

    if serializer_result.is_valid():
        serializer_result.save()
    else:
        logger.debug("Error with data {}.".format(serializer_result.errors))
```

When I run it locally after running the commands `python3 manage.py runserver` and `python3 migrate --database postgres`, it saves the results to `postgres`.

However on production I am getting the following error, when the function is executed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 108, in debug_sql
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anomaly_detection/views.py", line 23, in trigger_prediction_cronjob
    prediction_job()
  File "/anomaly_detection/access_logs_modeling.py", line 85, in prediction_job
    serializer_result.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 205, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 939, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 447, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 113, in debug_sql
    sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 155, in last_executed_query
    params = self._quote_params_for_last_executed_query(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 144, in _quote_params_for_last_executed_query
    return cursor.execute(sql, params).fetchone()
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your settings and the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` being set correctly.

Comment: It seems that your Django server is trying to connect to the SQLite3 database instead the Postgres, as you mentioned. Try to comment the lines about SQLite3 in the `settings.py` file. And run the server again.